# template does not exist, when invalid data is feed in form

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

In part_detail_view I am passing part_stock_form() to the template so that I will show the form to add stock in the DetailView.

```
class part_detail_view(DetailView):
    model = part_list
    context_object_name = 'part_detail'
    template_name = 'part_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(part_detail_view, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['my_list'] = populate_nav_bar()
        context['form'] = part_stock_form()
        return context
```

The CreateView of stock is given below

```
class stock_add_view(CreateView):
    model = part_stock
    fields = ['part_id','entry_date','supplier','amount','remaining']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('parts:part_list')
```

and the template of 'part_detail.html' is

```
<div>
{{ part_detail.part_id}}<br>
{{ part_detail.part_name }}<br>
{{ part_detail.cost }}<br>
{{ part_detail.available_quantity }}
</div>
<div >
<form method="post" action="{% url 'parts:stock_add_view'%}">
    {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.errors }}
          {{ form }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

when adding the stock through stock_add_view() the stock is added successfully but when invalid input is entered the error is shown like this 
[image: error description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateView` assumes that you have a template in the form of `model_name_form`. In your case, it is `part_stock_form.html`. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView):

> The CreateView page displayed to a GET request uses a template_name_suffix of '_form'. For example, changing this attribute to '_create_form' for a view creating objects for the example Author model would cause the default template_name to be 'myapp/author_create_form.html'

So, you need to create such a template with the name *part_stock_form.html*. If you want to use *part_detail.html*, try changing `template_name` variable in your view (untested):

```
class stock_add_view(CreateView):
    model = part_stock
    fields = ['part_id','entry_date','supplier','amount','remaining']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('parts:part_list')

    template_name = 'part_detail.html'
```

Hope it helps